# Raspbmc slow networking issues

Tags: networking, raspbmc

I have a Pi running Raspbmc by the TV and a desktop computer in the study. For a while, I had the TP-Link gigabit router next to the Pi and the desktop connected via household wired network cables. The household network was poorly configured and only getting 10Mbps speeds. I redid the network outlets making them gigabit-capable and moved the router into the study. Now I get 100Mbps speeds as measured by `iperf` (the Pi only supports 100Mbps). But for some reason Raspbmc's networking has become slower! Before, when I started a video it would spin up in a second or two. Now it takes 15 to 30 seconds. And if I try to switch to another video while one video is playing, playback stutters and slows down to nearly a halt.

Could the Pi's networking slow down because of its distance from the router? This is the only explanation I can think of, because nothing else has changed other than the router location and the added support for 1000BASE-T in the wiring.

To be clear about the wiring, previously the house was wired with only 2 twisted pairs being used per port. Being only [10BASE-T](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/10BASE-T) the maximum speed was 10Mbps. I rewired/recapped all the network cables so they now use all 4 twisted pairs and support gigabit speeds. I confirmed gigabit is working between two computers that have gigabit support. The Pi only has 100Mb support which I also confirmed is working.

EDIT: output of `ifconfig`:

```
eth0  Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:27:eb:0b:32:d8  
      inet addr:192.168.0.105  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::ba27:ebff:fe0b:32d8/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:125183 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:24397 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:170776152 (162.8 MiB)  TX bytes:2928810 (2.7 MiB)

lo    Link encap:Local Loopback  
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
      RX packets:571 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:571 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
      RX bytes:58730 (57.3 KiB)  TX bytes:58730 (57.3 KiB)
```

```

Comment: The Pi is connected using a ethernet cable. Right?

Comment: Did you try to transfer a huge file via *scp*? I just want to exclude problems with XBMC, SD card and any other minor invisible change.

Send a video using *scp* and check the average speed. See if matches with megabit connections.

Comment: Can you add some more information as well such as if you are running overclocked or not, where is the video streaming from, have you tested a different switch, what distribution of Raspbmc are you on and have you ran updates for the nightly builds?

Comment: post output from $ifconfig

Comment: @Kangkan, yes both the Pi and my desktop are connected via wired network.

Comment: @WillianPaixao I get 1.5MB/s transferring a large file with `scp`.

Comment: @MikeNaylor I'm running stock Raspbmc, build raspbmc-rls-1.0-hardfp-b20140527-u20140527, Debian-based, no overclocking, video over HDMI, streaming from my desktop. I don't have another router to test on. But this router works fine between a laptop and my desktop. I haven't run any updates yet, but I installed everything less than 2 months ago.

Comment: @j0h I will post output of `ifconfig` in the question because it's too long for a comment.

Comment: And I am sure your Pi LEDs (http://www.adafruit.com/blog/2013/02/15/raspberry-pi-status-leds-explained-piday-raspberrypi-raspberry_pi/) are showing that you are connected on 100mbps

Comment: The only thing I'm sure of is that if You don't exeed the 100m distans limit there is no speed problems, as long. as You use Cat 5e or higher. You should check that You are using default values in all network settings and autonegotiaton for speed and duplex. /Paxman

Comment: @Kangkan the 100Mbps light is on and yellow. I'm pretty sure I'm connected at 100Mbps. What I've noticed however is that opening videos inside of directories with lots of videos takes longer than opening videos in directories with fewer videos.

Comment: I would see if you have network package loss. Check it pinging for a quite long time.

Comment: @ReedG.Law - when you open a directory with lots of videos in the directory, is your Pi generating a thumbnail for each video, or downloading the thumbnails from the source system? 
The large file copy is likely limited by SD card, could you check if the speed is the same when writing to the SD card a large file as when writing to a flash drive (on the pi)?

Comment: which protocol are you using to access the movie: SMB, NFS, SSH?

Comment: Possibly the cable between your wall port and the Pi is broken?? Use another cable. Also try and do the same test with a tested cable connected directly to the router, not via the wiring system. Maybe the Pi is picking up some noise from a wiring error, ground loop maybe or no ground at all!!!

Comment: Reed G Law: update your Post with details. check out http://www.ufsdump.org/papers/linuxcon2010-linux-monitoring.pdf around page 26

Comment: @WillianPaixao I don't see any packet loss. All pings are less than 1 ms.

Comment: @user2813274 I believe the Pi is generating thumbnails. I'm not sure how this works, but that could be a reason for the slow down. With dd I get a write speed of 5.8 MB/s on the SD card. I get 3.5 MB/s on an external hard drive.

Comment: @jet I am using SSH.

Comment: @ReedG.Law - if the Pi is generating thumbnails, you should see the CPU spiking while it does that, and it could certainly explain a slow-down

Comment: how about using NFS, SSH has far more overhead. In my LAN, HD movies stuttering via SSH are fine via NFS (the same hardware, the same LAN)

Comment: @jet I switched over to NFS and indeed that solved it! It's as fast as a local drive now. Please leave an answer so I can award you the bounty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

how about using NFS, SSH has far more overhead. In my LAN, HD movies stuttering via SSH are fine via NFS (the same hardware, the same LAN)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend trying to overclock the RPi.  [This guide](http://htpcbuild.com/htpc-software/raspberry-pi-raspbmc/raspbmc-overclocking/) has how to overclock an RPi with RaspBMC.  Basically using SSH from another machine on your network edit the config.txt file.  I highly recommend reading about overclocking before just plugging in values.  Just from my experiences I have mine running at 900MHz following [this post](http://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=35&t=24636), the second response but with an overvolt of 2.  I'm able to stream HD movies with very little hesitation.

Also just in general, having a lot of files in a single folder increases load times anyways.  I'd suggest some sort of subdivision of folders.  I try to limit my folders to less than 20 items.

Comment: As a side note, it is possible that when your network was running at 10MBps the Pi was able to keep up but now the higher bandwidth is straining the Pi a bit and it's having to pre-cache some of the data.

Comment: I tried overclocking to 900MHz but there's no noticable difference. HD streaming works for me too, but starting videos sometimes takes over a minute.

Comment: I do notice that xbmc.bin is regularly using around 70% CPU and dropbear is using another 15%. I also tried putting a directory with almost 400 videos on an external hard drive to compare speed. The video that took over a minute to start playback over the network only took about 8 seconds from the external drive.

Comment: What is your memory split setting?

Comment: What is memory split? I didn't specify a frequency for sdram.

Comment: Try 450MHz for the SDRAM.  Memory split defines how much memory is allocated to the system and the GPU.  Here's a link to a discussion on it: http://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=91&t=58245

Comment: I'd recommend no less than 128MB to GPU, if it still lags try 256MB.  Here's another discussion on performance tuning an RPi with xbmc:  http://forum.xbmc.org/showthread.php?tid=190658

Comment: I don't experience any video lag now that the networking issue is resolved. Is there any other reason I should fiddle with GPU RAM?

Comment: Didn't see you'd resolved it.  I wouldn't recommend adjusting it if things are working.  The reason for suggesting it was to ensure you didn't have too much allocated to the GPU and not enough to the system.  Glad you figured it out.

Answer (score -2):

Disable the firewall in Raspbmc Settings

Should this still not resolve -- please email me

Sam Nazarko

http://raspbmc.com

Comment: The op says there is no change in the Pi except the LAN cable connections. How can this be an answer?